# LAMP and PHP Issue

Tags: php, apache

I have a working LAMP server ( I think). When I enter the server's ip address into firefox I get the picture shown on this page.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

This leads me to believe everything is fine. But in my directory where PHP files are to be placed (/var/www/html) I have placed two files. Hello.php which contains:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>PHP Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
   </body>
  </html>
```

If I type my IP address into firefox then `/hello.php` the output "Hello World" is visible. The second file, `/info.php`, contains:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

When I try IP address followed by /info.php. I get a blank white screen with no output. In my httpd.conf file I have added (LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so). If I go to /etc/apache2/mods-available there are no php modules in this directory (not sure if there should be).

I am new to servers, as well as PHP. I am running apache2, php 7.0.6 and Ubuntu 12.04.

If there is any other information needed please ask. Thank you.

Comment: Check the error logs. I've noticed that `phpinfo()` may throw some notices about setting the default timezone and under certain situations of error reporting these may cause a script termination.

Comment: For every error is an error log :) Try look at /var/log/apache2

If not enabled enable all php errors in your apache2/php.ini

My guess here is you have a blanck new line after your closing php tag ?>
Also the php end tag is not mandatory, even not recommended in case of pure php files, for that problem and others of that kind like headers not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try a PHP page with only this in it:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
phpinfo();
?>
```

Look at your client-side debugger (Firebug, etc.) if you have one, or look at your apache logs.

Comment: Thank you for this luigiBaby. I fixed the problem, and this page now works as well. I guess I had missed one package during installation and that was the cause of all the problems.