# Possible bad PHP installation - info page blank - LAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, lamp

First I'm a total beginner here.

I try to run a local Wordpress setup, so in ubuntu 18.04 I installed Apache, MySQL, and php. Apache and MySQL setup is fine.

1. I run:

   ```
   sudo ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
   ```

   output: 192.168.1.100

   I go to **192.168.1.100/index.html** in my browser and **Apache2
   Ubuntu Default Page** shows up.
2. Then I put **info.php** file in **/var/www/html/** to see if php is
   installed correctly, but when I go to **192.168.1.100/info.php** to
   test if php is working I get a white blank page. With the following
   in page source code.

   ```
   <?php
   phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```
3. **#REAL DEAL#** Strangely enough when I put **info.php** in **/home/user/** and then I run

   ```
   php -S localhost:8000
   ```

   and then go to **localhost:8000/info.php** to test php the **purple
   php information page shows up**!

Why it doesn't show at **192.168.1.100/info.php**? Is php correctly installed? Is this way also accepted? Is this ever right? What’s going on and what is wrong?
I Also read this topic:
[LAMP and PHP Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304136/lamp-and-php-issue) but didn't figure out anything.

Comment: because your current working path is `/home/user` in terminal. Change your current path to `/var/www/html` by `cd` command than run the other command

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But why it doesn't show at 192.168.1.100/info.php?

Comment: I added this as answer. Please mark the answer as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are currently in `/home/user` in terminal and you run `php -S localhost:8000` from this directory. That's why php open server from this directory.

Change your current working directory to `/var/www/html` by run this command `cd /var/www/html` and than run the command `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: Thank you. But why it doesn't show at 192.168.1.100/info.php?

Comment: maybe your server is not running in default port.